# How can I parse the following string using logstash (grok)?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-4, logstash-grok

How can I parse the following string::

> 20160521015157802,PLABATCH,PPSDVALD,2016-05-21 00:23:42,2016-05-21
>   01:51:57,70,119,0,0,65,0,N

I want all values(comma separated values) in different variable to automate log checking process

> using kibana,logstash and elasticsearch

Comment: Maybe you should explain what those variables and values are supposed to be?

Comment: for example:
id=>20160521015157802
timestart=>2016-05-21 00:23:42
timeend=>2016-05-21 01:51:57
passed=>N

Answer (score 0):

You're really asking us to solve your problem for you. This site is to help people with problems they have already attempted to solve before. In addition, you may want to supply more information such as, what a sample output/result would look like.

If each logline is a series of comma separated values which are always in the same order then you could use the [csv](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html) filter in logstash with the [columns](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html#plugins-filters-csv-columns) defined.

#### Example

Input:

```
12:34, 5555, 13:54
```

Filter

```
csv {
  source => "message"
  columns => ['time_in', 'id', 'time_out']
}
```

Result:

```
time_in => 12:34
id => 5555
time_out => 13:54
```

Comment: okay next time i will try to give all the information [Will](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5216668/will-barnwell).
Thanks that helped :)